# How to rollback a superclass constructor

Tags: java

There are 3 classes: `Base`, `Derived` and a `Registry`:

```
class Base {
  Base() {
    Registry.register(this);
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  Derived() {
    // throws an exception here
  }
}
```

Is there any way to unregister the half-constructed object from the `Registry` when the `Derived` constructor throws an exception?

I know this is an anti-pattern because `this` is used within a constructor. I am searching for a better design, something like `Base.listInstances()`.

Comment: How do you unregister when the object is dead?

Comment: Use factory pattern. Create object and register it only if object creation is successful.

Comment: The object is explicitly unregistered within `dispose()`. `Base` extends `JInternalFrame` and `Registry` is a desktop pane who needs to know something about its internal windows.

Comment: Calling `Registry.register(this)` from the constructor is a bad idea, irrespective of whether you need to unregister again: this is an example of *unsafe publication*, because you are giving out a reference to the instance before it is fully initialized. This is a path to bugs.

Comment: You are right: doing so is a code smell. And I am aware of that. How to refactor the current design?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unregister method you can go like this.

```
class Base {
    Base() {
        Registry.register(this);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    super();
    try {
        // do stuff
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Registry.unregister(this);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

If not you should only register it when Object was created successfully (you have to modify `Base` for that if you are allowed to do that).

Comment: Yes, my bad, sorry. Corrected it ;)